# PHP: Adding years to a timestamp

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, leap-year

In  PHP given a UTC timestamp I would like to add exactly N number of years. This should take into consideration leap years.

Thank you.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
$newTimestamp = strtotime('+2 years', $timestamp);
```

Replace "+2 years" as required.

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @NullUserException: Looks pretty obvious that you'd replace `2` with `N`, and that `$timestamp` contains the proper timestamp. Nowhere does it say in Jeff's code that `$timestamp` = now.

Comment: It's an example ... with the proviso, "replace +2 years as required" :P

Answer (score 9):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10Y'));
```

adds 10 years (`10Y`) to "today". DateTime's only in PHP 5.3, though.

Comment: +1, didn't know that one! On a sidenote, do you know some good text/book/tutorial on the new stuff to v5.3? Except official manual.

Comment: Not offhand. The php site has a good changelog/migration tutorial, though. I tend to avoid PHP books, because they're either hideously out of date, poorly written (e.g. lead you to write very bad insecure code), or just wildly wrong.

Comment: Not fully correct: DateTime is in since 5.2, only DateInterval was added for 5.3.

Comment: This is a good solution, I'm just sorry we don't have php 5.3.

Comment: In that case, the strtotime() options in the other answers will work for you.

Comment: what does `P` in `P10Y` stands for?

Comment: P stands for "Period"

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should consider when you do this.

```
$newTimestamp = strtotime('+2 years', $timestamp);
```

This adds up 2 years ( 720 or 721 days). In case you just want to keep the same day and month and add 2 extra years in the timestamp

you have to use mktime.

Example

```
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year+2);`
```

Comment: Now days you should use a library like Carbon to do all this time/date staff in php. It makes it a joy to work with dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date    = "1998-08-14";

$newdate = strtotime ( '+2 years' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );

echo $newdate;
```

echos

```
2000-08-14
```

Answer (score -1):

If for any reason you already have the actual timestamp, you could just add 31536000 to it.